# Validate whether checkbox with the same name is selected in different groups

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several checkboxes on a page that contains the same name. However, they are arranged in rows in a table so that they can be selected by the user. So, I **need to validate if at least one checkbox in each row is selected**.

The following image visually shows the page for this problem:
[image]

The following code is only a part of all the code that generates the above image.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Ensino Fundamental</label>
        <div class="form-check m-l-10">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="1anoensinofundamental" name="OfertaSerie" value="63" data-oferta-nivel-ensino="1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="1anoensinofundamental">1&#186; ano</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="2anoensinofundamental" name="OfertaSerie" value="64" data-oferta-nivel-ensino="1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="2anoensinofundamental">2&#186; ano</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="3anoensinofundamental" name="OfertaSerie" value="51" data-oferta-nivel-ensino="1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="3anoensinofundamental">3&#186; ano</label>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group m-t-20">
        <label>Ensino M&#233;dio</label>
        <div class="form-check m-l-10">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="1serieensinomedio" name="OfertaSerie" value="45" data-oferta-nivel-ensino="2">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="1serieensinomedio">1&#170; s&#233;rie</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="2serieensinomedio" name="OfertaSerie" value="54" data-oferta-nivel-ensino="2">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="2serieensinomedio">2&#170; s&#233;rie</label>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your post does not contain a question and also no example code how you tried to solve the issue yet. Assuming that you want to do the validation for each, there's basically two ways:
- You assign unique IDs to all checkboxes, e.g. ano1matutino etc. and check these programatically.
- You access a certain div representing a row (should give IDs to the divs) and then check all checkbox elements within that div.

Comment: @ErikReder Yes, because I could not create a logic to perform this validation. I have been learning javascript about 2 months ago :(

Comment: I stated this, because as I understand, that's basically the rules of stackoverflow. Nevertheless, some further hints in my edited comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to validate by **column** you could do something like below, because thats how you checkboxes appear to are organized in the DOM. To validate by **row** you would have to provide all of your HTML because I can only make educated assumptions as to how the rest of your HTML is structured....

```
function validateChecks(){
    var groups = $('.form-group');

    var failedGroups = 0;

    groups.each(function () {
        var columns = $(this).find('.form-check'),
            failedColumns = 0;

            columns.each(function (){
                var checks = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]'),
                    failedChecks = 0;

                checks.each(function (){
                    var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
                    if (!checked) failedChecks++;
                }) 
                if (failedChecks > 0) failedColumns++;
            })
            if (failedColumns > 0) failedGroups++;
    })

    if (failedGroups > 0) {
        console.log("One of the columns isn't valid!")
    }
}
```